# Insert ornaments in the footer of each page of the book

Tags: books, footer

I'm writing a book on GeoGebra that I will use to teach at school. I used The Legrand Orange Book template and modified its appearance as shown in the following image.
[image]
I want to insert an ornament (for example an ornament with the number 88) in the footer of every page of the book. As shown in the following figure.
[image]
How to? Thus this question. Thank you for any information and answers given.

Comment: Does that template use the `fancyhdr` package? If it does, you can define the content of page footers, however you wish. See `fancyhdr` documentation. But since most of use here do not use that template, we would have to guess.

Comment: Yes, template use the fancyhdr package.

Comment: Good! Then you will be able to solve the problem yourself. It would be possible, but difficult, for us to do it for you. What you need to do is define the `fancyfoot` command so that it places what you want, where you want it. And, you will need to use pagestyle fancy. EDIT: See the answer posted below, by hair-splitter.

Answer (score 3):

The following code shows a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\color{green!50!black}\pgfornament[width=4cm]{88}}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: **Thank you Sir**.